# How to retrieve earliest record only on group by multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to obtain the record with the earliest time value for each user's daily entries. At this point I can see the the user's record group for the day, however it selects all entries instead of the earliest one only as I was hoping to achieve with MIN(). Is there any way to remove the extra records?

```
SELECT t.UserID,
       t.RecordID, 
       CAST(t.Date AS date)as UpdateDate,
       MIN(CAST(t.Date AS time)) as UpdateTime,
       t.RecordTypeID as RecordT)ype
       FROM Table1 t WITH(NOLOCK)
       WHERE t.UserID IS NOT NULL 
            AND t.UserID <>'' 
            AND t.LastUpdated > CAST('2010-01-01' AS date)
            and CAST(t.Date AS date) > GETDATE()
            group BY t.UserID,
                     CAST(t.Date AS date), 
                     CAST(t.Date AS time),
                     t.uniqueid,
                     t.RecordTypeID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `top with ties` to get the earliest daily entry for each user and day. :

```
select top 1 with ties
    t.UserID
  , t.RecordID
  , cast(t.date as date) as UpdateDate
  , cast(t.date as time) as UpdateTime
  , t.RecordTypeID as RecordType
from Table1 t
where t.UserID is not null 
  and t.UserID <> '' 
  and t.LastUpdated > cast('2010-01-01' as date) 
  and cast(t.date as date) > getdate() /* future only? */
order by row_number() over (
  partition by t.UserId, cast(t.date as date)
  order by t.date
  )
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I thought the group by might not cut it for this specific situation but was not aware of top with ties. Learned something new today :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use aggregation function over a column You cant get the aggregation function (min ) and group by for the same column

you must exclude from group by the column that are involved  in aggregation function   eg:

```
SELECT t.UserID,
       CAST(t.Date AS date) as UpdateDate,
       MIN(CAST(t.Date AS time)) as UpdateTime,
       t.RecordTypeID as RecordT)ype
       FROM Table1 t WITH(NOLOCK)
       WHERE t.UserID IS NOT NULL 
            AND t.UserID <>'' 
            AND t.LastUpdated > CAST('2010-01-01' AS date)
            and CAST(t.Date AS date) > GETDATE()
            group BY t.UserID,
                     CAST(t.Date AS date),
                     t.RecordTypeID
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yes I had figured that much, unfortunately I still need the recordID column and when I add it back to this query I again get multiple results rather than a single one per day. @SqlZim answer does do the trick for me but appreciate the pointer.